# Why is my "if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid()" not working?

Tags: javascript, python, django

So I have been trying to implement a feature on my website to be able to post with multiple images in it. I am not sure why if I make an if statement for both project_forms.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid() my code is not working. But if it is just either one of them they work fine.

I don't have any errors popping up its just that it is not doing what it is supposed to do. No images or posts go to my database.

The way I implemented my multiple image upload is to have a separate table for the posts and multiple image upload but are linked with a foreign key.

Here are my code:

views.py

```
def create_projects(request):
    # Special case if the request method is not POST

    project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    p_formset = P_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        # Checks if the form is valid before save
    if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid():
        instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        p_photos = p_formset.save(commit=False)
        p_photos.save()

        data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': p_photos.p_file.name, 'url': p_photos.p_file.url}

        return JsonResponse(data)

    else:

        data = {'is_valid': False}

    context = { 
    'project_form': project_form,
    'p_formset': p_formset,
    }
    return render(request, 'projects/forms.html', context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.utils.text import slugify
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from PIL import Image

import os

DEFAULT_IMAGE_ID = 1

# Create your models here.
class Projects(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='files/', blank=True)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field = 'img_height', width_field = 'img_width',blank=True)
    img_height = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=600)
    img_width = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Generates a random string 
        unique_string = get_random_string(length=32)

        # Combines title and unique string to slugify
        slugtext = self.title + "-" + "unique_id=-" + unique_string
        self.slug = slugify(slugtext)

        return super(Projects, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def get_p_image_filename(instance, filename):
    title = instance.p_post.title
    slug_title = slugify(title)
    return "post_images/%s-%s" % (slug_slug, filename)

class P_Images(models.Model):
    p_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', blank=None)
    p_uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    #p_post = models.ForeignKey(Projects, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=DEFAULT_IMAGE_ID)
```

The variable for the foreign key was commented out because of a separate issue. I am trying to fix it by trying to solve this problem so that things can go to my database.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Projects, P_Images

class ProjectsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Projects
        #file_field = forms.FileField(widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}))
        fields = ('images','title', 'description',)


class P_ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #p_image = forms.ImageField(label='Image')  
    class Meta:
        model = P_Images
        fields = ('p_file',)
```

basic-upload.js

```
$(function () {
    /* 1. OPEN THE FILE EXPLORER WINDOW */
    $(".js-upload-photos").click(function () {
      $("#fileupload").click();
    });

    /* 2. INITIALIZE THE FILE UPLOAD COMPONENT */
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
      dataType: 'json',
      done: function (e, data) {  /* 3. PROCESS THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER */
        if (data.result.is_valid) {
          $("#gallery tbody").prepend(
            "<tr><td><a href='" + data.result.url + "'>" + data.result.name + "</a></td></tr>"
          )
        }
      }
    });

  });
```

Comment: What does this have to do with javascript?

Comment: Oh part of the multiple file upload is handled in jquery. I should include it.

Comment: @charlietfl hey! I am not sure where am I doing that. It is working as long as I dont make a comparison for the both of them.

Comment: Currently you're not displaying the errors you get, only {'is_valid': False}. You can either display the errors in your template (which is move obvious and user-friendly) or add a breakpoint, for example with ipdb, and look into project_form and p_formset errors attribute, it'll show you what's wrong.

Comment: @mxle hey! sorry i wasn't able to respond right away as I was at work. I am not exactly sure how can I display the errors in my template. I would love to know it tho! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to separate your function in two, the first one would render the form, the second would answer the api call. I think you should do this, because a function should return one type of content and here you have two: JSON and HTML. I suggest you do it like this:

```
@require_http_methods(["GET"])
def get_create_form(request):
    context = { 
        'project_form': ProjectsForm(),
        'p_formset': P_ImageForm(),
    }

    return render(request, 'projects/forms.html', context)

@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def create_projects(request):
    project_form = ProjectsForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    p_formset = P_ImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

    # Checks if the form is valid before save
    if project_form.is_valid() and p_formset.is_valid():
        instance = project_form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        p_photos = p_formset.save(commit=False)
        p_photos.save()

        data = {
            'is_valid': True, 
            'name': p_photos.p_file.name, 
            'url': p_photos.p_file.url
        }

    else:
        data = {
            'is_valid': False,
            'errors': form.errors.as_json()
        }

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: hi! this actually make sense for better code! Thank you! However it is posting method_not_allowed(POST) whenever I add images.

Comment: @EllyRichardson Have you added an url for the second view function and changed it accordingly in your frontend code?